# How to create grouped filters based on integer range?

Tags: entities, views

I'm developing a recruitment website which will allow users to filter jobs by salary. It has been designed so that the filter is grouped into salary ranges like this...

[image]

I am using the Range module in order to add a range field to my job content type (essentially just two text boxes). The idea is that the admin can enter in any 'from' and 'to' integer (doesn't have to be a value that matches one of the filters e.g. £20–25k). Instead the query should be able to adapt and show any matching results.

The issue I have is that because I essentially have two fields saved there doesn't appear to be any simple way of grouping filters. I have attempted to use the `Global: Combine fields` filter but this only works with strings, not integers.

I've also attempted to add the `Salary range filter` included with the Range module under the `Filter criteria` heading of my view but this doesn't appear to work either. Here is a screenshot of what I attempted (I'm assuming that the Range module doesn't actually store the integers in-between the 'to and 'from' fields so I guess this wouldn't work. I'm also not sure that separating the values with commas is valid either).

[image]

The only method I can think of would be finding a way of adding the two fields together to create one total integer which would then allow me to use the standard `is-between` operator available when filtering a single field in Views.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Contextual Range Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/contextual_range_filter

According to the documentation, this allows you to make a contextual filter based on a range (as opposed to just a single field value).